# Plot GIS polar data on BlueMarble in Python

Tags: python, geopandas

This is my first time working with GIS data and I would like to plot ice sheet extent on a world map with backround centered on the pole.

The shapefile I'm using can be downloaded here: ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02135/south/monthly/shapefiles/shp_extent/01_Jan/extent_N_197901_polygon_v3.0.zip

I think the coordinates of the data are some sort of polar coordinates because they look like this:

```
shapefile Reader
    135 shapes (type 'POLYGON')
    135 records (2 fields)
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': (((-675000.0, 4675000.0), (-625000.0, 4675000.0), (-625000.0, 4625000.0), (-650000.0, 4625000.0), (-650000.0, 4575000.0), (-675000.0, 4575000.0), (-675000.0, 4675000.0)),)}
```

I'm trying to plot this shapefile on top of a BlueMarble Earth (or any other background). However, the polar coordinates are giving me problems. I tried to plot it using GeoPandas.

```
import geopandas
import contextily as ctx

df = geopandas.read_file(shp_file)
df = df.to_crs(epsg=3857)

ax = df.plot(figsize=(10, 10), alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
```

This, however, results in several problems as you can see here:
[image: geopandas_output]

What should I change in this Python script? Or point me in the right direction?

Update:

Based on the comment from Ian Turton I was able to google a bit more and change my code to the following:

```
df_N = geopandas.read_file(shp_file_N)
df_N = df_N.to_crs(epsg=3031)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot()

df_N.plot(ax=ax1, figsize=(10, 10), color="white", alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
ctx.add_basemap(ax=ax1, url=cartodb_url)
ax1.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

However, the shape and the map are not lining up correctly. If anyone can help me with this step that would be very helpful!

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `to_crs`?

Comment: 3857 is a very poor choice for polar regions

Comment: Thank you Ian Turton! I looked into it and got a little bit further. Now the main problem is that the shape is on the wrong part of the map. Do you know how to make adjustments to this?

Comment: Ian is correct that you cannot use Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) for the poles (check the area of use at https://epsg.io/3857). However, contextily to plot the background map requires EPSG:3857 by default. But the `add_basemap` function has a `crs` keyword where you can pass a different CRS if your data is in a different CRS.